# How can I target a one specific page on my wordpress website to show a responsive layout?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, html, woothemes

The website and page in question is weddings.blaskphotography.com.au/photographs

I'd like to have this page, when viewed on an iPhone, to target the mobile stylesheet that Woothemes has included in the Canvas theme I am using.

I am using a child theme called, woo-child

I wish to have the rest of the website display as normal like its a scaled down desktop view. I have a mindmap and a form which doesn't fit when I choose to have the entire website target a responsive layout css file. This is simply a checkbox, on or off in wordpress.

So in the end, I'm looking for a clear explanation of how I would go about doing this in steps. What style sheets am I looking for in filezilla?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media queries to load specific stylesheets on different resolutions.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/narrow.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px)' href='<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/medium.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 901px)' href='<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/css/wide.css' />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Where do I enter this code? On the Custom.css on the themes options under wordpress?
Also, what exactly do I replace out of this? The php bloginfo ('templete_url') and locate the relevant .css file right?

Comment: You have to place this in your header.php in the <head></head> section. You have to place the files in a folder called css under wp-content/themes/your-theme/css

Comment: ok, so I place the code above in the header.php head section. Then, I have to place what files in the themes css? Where do I look for the php bloginfo? Where do I find the 'template_url'? I have to make the narrow, medium and wide css and this is what goes in the wp-content/themes/your-theme/css

Comment: the bloginfo('template_url'); is your themes folder url. So make a folder there called css and place the new css files in there.

Comment: so are you telling me that I have to write 3 separate css files ? Good luck to me

Comment: No. not at all. You have two stylesheets. A responsive one, and a normal one. Use those two with the code I provided, 3 was just an example..